# What are the medals you can earn on levels?

Tags: dungeon-defenders

I noticed that I have a few "Knight", "Immortal" medals on various levels. So I was wondering: Are there any list of all medals you can earn on a level, and what are the requirements for earning them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a [page on an unofficial wiki](http://dungeondefenders.wikia.com/wiki/Awards) that seems to have a good-sized list of potential awards you can earn. Listed again below:

> **End of Wave Awards**
>
> - Knight - Killed 10 enemies in 5 seconds
> - Lord - Killed 50 enemies in 5 seconds
> - Invincible - Did not take damage for an entire wave after the first
> - Master Builder - Kept full Defense Units throughout the wave
>
> **End of Wave Awards in Multiplayer**
>
> - First Kill - Scored the first kill in the wave
> - Janitor - Scored the last kill in the wave
> - Chillax - Moved the least distance in the wave
>
> **End of Mission Awards**
>
> - Immortal - Did not die throughout the entire match
> - Master Strategist - Only used Defenses to harm enemies after the initial wave
> - Gunslinger - Only used Abilities & Weapons to harm enemies after the initial wave
> - Flawless Victory - No core damage after the first wave
> - Boss Slayer - Your Hero or Defense landed the killing blow on a boss
> - Skin of Your Teeth - Completed the match with less or equal to 100 hp on the Crystal
>
> **End of Mission Awards in Multiplayer**
>
> - Banker - Earned the most mana
> - Trigger Happy - Most first to ready for combat phase
> - Handy Man - Performed the most tower repairs
> - Mechanic - Performed the most tower upgrades
> - Strategist - Scored the most tower kills
> - Most Valuable Hero - Scored the most player kills
> - Most Valuable Player - Scored the most total kills
> - Teamwork - Completed a mission with 4 active players